# $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $a_n\not=0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$. Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{3+a_n}-\sqrt{3}}{a_n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

I already multiplied by the conjugate so I get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{3+a_n}+\sqrt{3}}$$
but I dont know how to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{3+a_n}=\sqrt{3}$.
Also I already tried with the definition with the limit $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}$, but is more hard. Can anyone help me? Also important to say that $a_n$ is a sequence.

Answer (score 2):

We know that for positive values, $\sqrt{ \cdot }$ is a continuous function, meaning that the limit of the function is the function of the limit.  So $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{3+a_n}=\sqrt{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(3+a_n)}$.  Find $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 3+a_n$ and you should be good!

Comment: If you'd like to be extremely thorough, you can show this fact.  Using the triangle inequality we have $|\sqrt{x_n} - \sqrt{a}|^2=|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{a}| \cdot |\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{a}|\leq |\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{a}| \cdot |\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{a}|=|x_n-a|$.  So if $x_n \rightarrow a$, choose $N$ large enough such that $n \geq N$ implies $|x_n-a|<\varepsilon^2$.  Then $\sqrt{x_n} \rightarrow \sqrt{a}$.  Now just let $x_n=3+a_n$ and $a$ be your limit.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sqrt{\phantom{1}}$ is a continuous function we obtain:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\sqrt{3+a_n}=\sqrt{\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}(3+a_n)}=\sqrt3.$$

Answer (score 1):

As, $\sqrt{3+x} $ continuous for $x>0$

So, we can take the limit inside of the function.

Using the rule, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{(3+a_n)} = \sqrt{(3+\lim_{n\to\infty}  a_n) } = \sqrt{3} $$

Comment: Whenever, this continuity applicable for a continuous function on whole $\mathbb{R} $, then it is automatically applicable for all arbitrary sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

Let $\epsilon>0$.

Thus, since $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}a_n=0$, there is $N$ such that for any $n>N$ we have $3+a_n\geq0$ and $$|a_{n}|<\sqrt3\epsilon.$$
Thus, $$|\sqrt{3+a_n}-\sqrt3|=\frac{|a_n|}{\sqrt{3+a_n}+\sqrt3}\leq\frac{|a_n|}{\sqrt3}<\epsilon,$$ Which says $$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\sqrt{3+a_n}=\sqrt3.$$

Indeed, we proved that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is $N$ such that for any $n>N$ we have:
$$|\sqrt{3+a_n}-\sqrt3|<e,$$ which by the definition of a limit gives $$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\sqrt{3+a_n}=\sqrt3.$$

Comment: i dont understand. I know that, since $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$, $\forall \epsilon'>0$, $\exists N'\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geqslant N'$, $|a_n|<\epsilon'$.

I want to prove that, $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geqslant N$, $|\sqrt{a_n+3}-\sqrt{3}|<\epsilon$

Comment: @Bojko Yair Kuzmanovski Reyes Yes, I used  the definition of a limit. See please better my post. I proved it.

Comment: yeah, i know you are using the definition, but i dont know to use the definition of a limit, can yoy explain a little bit more

Comment: @Bojko Yair Kuzmanovski ReyesI added. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: I let $\epsilon>0$. I know that for all $\epsilon'$, $|a_n-0|<\epsilon'$, in particular, for $\epsilon'=\sqrt{3}\epsilon$. Why are you sayinh that $3+a_n\geqslant 0$, because the only thing I know is that $a_n\not=0$?

Comment: @Bojko Yair Kuzmanovski Reyes Because $a_n\rightarrow0$. There is $N_1$ such that for any $n>N_1$ we have $|a_n|<3,$ which gives $-3<a_n<3$ and from here  $3+a_n>0$.

Comment: @Bojko Yair Kuzmanovski Reyes Now we can take $N\geq N_1$.

Comment: all right, i think i get it. We need that $a_n+3\geqslant 0$ so $\sqrt{a_n+3}$ is defined, this is our first condition, I mean $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$. And also, the only think we know is that $\frac{|a_n|}{\sqrt{a_n+3}+\sqrt{3}}\leqslant \frac{|a_n|}{\sqrt{3}}$ which leads us to choose the $N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n|<\sqrt{3}\epsilon$.

The question know is, what about the relation between $N_1$ and $N_2$. I've always need to take the greatest?

Comment: @Gauss Yes, of course.

Comment: @Gauss I wait your reaction...

Comment: I finally start get it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

$$\begin {align} \lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt {3+a_n}=\sqrt {\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(3+a_n\right)}=\sqrt {\lim_{n\to \infty }3+\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n}=\sqrt {3+0}=\sqrt 3\end{align} $$